# Register the Android App with C2DM

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I am using the Emulator of version 8. and when i am trying to register the Android Application then it will gives the null registration ID. Please help me to resolve this issue. How can i register the Android Application with C2DM.My code is to register the App.

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(startCode.this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); // boilerplate
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "12786@gmail.com");
startService(registrationIntent); 
handleRegistration(getApplicationContext(), registrationIntent);


private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id"); 
        if (intent.getStringExtra("error") != null) {
            // Registration failed, should try again later.
            Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR");
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra("unregistered") != null) {
            // unregistration done, new messages from the authorized sender will be rejected
            Log.e("unregistered", "unregistered");
        } else if (registration != null) {
           // Send the registration ID to the 3rd party site that is sending the messages.
           // This should be done in a separate thread.
           // When done, remember that all registration is done. 
            Log.e("registration", registration);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, you need to add a google account in your emulator.

You can only do so with target of Google APIs 8, not Android 2.2.

Comment: I am using the Google APIs 8 and i have already create the account in the emulator but how can i send the notification to my emulator

Comment: The registration process is entirely automated and works fine in the emulator. You need to have a Google account set up, as mentioned, but then your register code should result in a registration response (and thus a C2DM ID). If you aren't getting the ID back, then you're missing something else (a permission, perhaps? check logcat).

Comment: "Sending a notification" to the emulator via the C2DM channels still needs Google servers to work. There's no "emulate" C2DM message option, you have to send one through the Google servers using the instructions outlined here: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#server