# how to register an app to C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Register the Android App with C2DM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757576/register-the-android-app-with-c2dm)

so, I've been looking all over and reading everything I can put my hands on to check how to use C2DM with my super-cool chat app.

I saw that there was all sorts of stuff that my server guy has to take care of but I hadn't understood one thing.

The registration process has to include a senderId, that is basically a Google ID that is being transfered to the Google server as the app (or user) that is using the app, this identifies you as a push client.

My question is, **do I have to prompt the user with a registration dialog?** it seems like a horrible thing to do to my users since the app already uses Facebook connect and prompting too much of those are hostile for the users and will for sure make them uninstall the app.

what is the process of one app, registering for C2DM? and how can I use the already existing authentication token that the Google Play uses?

---

I read (for the third time) Vogella's turoial on using C2DM and this is the basis of my question:

```
public void register(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    intent.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    intent.putExtra("sender", "youruser@gmail.com");  //WHICH EMAIL?
    startService(intent);
}
```

is the Email used in the 4th line the device owner's email or the service email?

If we're talking about the user, is there a way of acquiring this without another authentication dialog? I already have a Facebook login and I don't want to cause the user discomfort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the article of vogella , very brief implement guide for C2DM.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

All the things mention over there as well as code, I personally implement its code and that is working fine.

Comment: the gmail id used in register function is the person's id who develop application & wish to send C2DM messages to mobile user.

second thing is that you need not to display registration dialog.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [signup](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/signup) with google's C2DM

Second get a Auth token for your C2DM application

```
function(){
        // Create the post data
        // Requires a field with the email and the password
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Email=").append(email);
        builder.append("&Passwd=").append(password);
        builder.append("&accountType=GOOGLE");
        builder.append("&source=MyLittleExample");
        builder.append("&service=ac2dm");

        // Setup the Http Post
        byte[] data = builder.toString().getBytes();
        URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length));

        // Issue the HTTP POST request
        OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream();
        output.write(data);
        output.close();

        // Read the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        String auth_key = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {
                auth_key = line.substring(5);
            }
        }

        // Finally get the authentication token
        // To something useful with it
        return auth_key;
}
```

Now you need to register the client mobile device to C2DM to receive the updates

```
public void register(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    intent.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    intent.putExtra("sender", "youruser@gmail.com");
    startService(intent);
}
```

The service will asynchronously register with Google and will send the "**com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION**" intent upon successful registration. Your application need to register an Broadcast Receiver for this intent. This also requires the usage of a permission based on your package as the Android system checks this internally.

```
<receiver android:name=".C2DMMessageReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"></action>
        <category android:name="de.vogella.android.c2dm.simpleclient" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

//

```
public class C2DMRegistrationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.w("C2DM", "Registration Receiver called");
    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
        Log.w("C2DM", "Received registration ID");
        final String registrationId = intent
                .getStringExtra("registration_id");
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

        Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId
                + ", error = " + error);
        // Send and store this in your application server(unique for each device)
    }
}
}
```

Now you can start sending C2DM messages through your server

```
private final static String AUTH = "authentication";

    private static final String UPDATE_CLIENT_AUTH = "Update-Client-Auth";

    public static final String PARAM_REGISTRATION_ID = "registration_id";

    public static final String PARAM_DELAY_WHILE_IDLE = "delay_while_idle";

    public static final String PARAM_COLLAPSE_KEY = "collapse_key";

    private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

    public static int sendMessage(String auth_token, String registrationId,
            String message) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        postDataBuilder.append(PARAM_REGISTRATION_ID).append("=")
                .append(registrationId);
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append(PARAM_COLLAPSE_KEY).append("=")
                .append("0");
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append("data.payload").append("=")
                .append(URLEncoder.encode(message, UTF8));

        byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes(UTF8);

        // Hit the dm URL.

        URL url = new URL("https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send");
        HttpsURLConnection
                .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new CustomizedHostnameVerifier());
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                Integer.toString(postData.length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="
                + auth_token);

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        return responseCode;
    }
```

[Reference](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

Comment: this is the **vogella blog post** word by word. I saw it and doesn't answer anything

Comment: i just referred that post instead of giving a external link this would be better. what you need exactly?

Comment: you already found the answer... good